# Não estou conseguindo/sabendo usar o Setter

Tags: java, getters-setters

Estou tentando fazer uns testes no JAVA aqui e estou com problemas:

A classe dos produtos, com a inicialização e os `getters/setters`

```
public class Produtos {

    private  String[] nomeItem = {"Item 1","Item 2","Item 3","Item 4","Item 5"};
    private  String[] categoriaItem  = {"Utensílio","Utensílio","Utensílio","Utensílio","Utensílio"};
    private  String[] medidaItem = {"Un","Un","Un","Un","Un"};
    private  String[] dispobinItem = {"5","5","10" ,"10","20"};


    public void iniciaEstoque(String[] nomeItem, String[] categoriaItem, String[] medidaItem, String[] disponibiItem){

        setNomeItem(nomeItem);
        setCategoriaItem(categoriaItem);
        setMedidaItem(medidaItem);
        setDisponibiItem(disponibiItem);

    }


    public String[] getNomeItem() {
        return nomeItem;
    }

    public void setNomeItem(String[] nomeItem) {
        this.nomeItem = nomeItem;
    }

    public String[] getCategoriaItem() {
        return categoriaItem;
    }

    public void setCategoriaItem(String[] categoriaItem) {
        this.categoriaItem = categoriaItem;
    }

    public String[] getMedidaItem() {
        return medidaItem;
    }

    public void setMedidaItem(String[] medidaItem) {
        this.medidaItem = medidaItem;
    }

    public String[] getDisponibiItem() {
        return dispobinItem;
    }

    public void setDisponibiItem(String[] dispobinItem) {
        this.dispobinItem = dispobinItem;
    }

}
```

A função para a inserção de um elemento novo:

```
public class InsereElementos {

    public String[] insereElemento(String[] array, String item){

        int indice;
        int tamanho = array.length;

        String[] arrayDummy = new String[tamanho+1];


            for(indice=0;indice<tamanho;indice++){
                arrayDummy[indice] = array[indice];
            }


            arrayDummy[indice] = item;

            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrayDummy));

            return arrayDummy;

        }

}
```

O main:

```
public class Principal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String nome = "x";

        String[] dummy = new Produtos().getNomeItem();

        String[] junta = new InsereElementos().insereElemento(dummy, nome);

        new Produtos().setNomeItem(junta);

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(new Produtos().getNomeItem()));
    }

}
```

Ao executar, um syso na função que insere mostra (retorna):
[Item 1, Item 2, Item 3, Item 4, Item 5, x]

Mas no *main* ao tentar dar *get* no *array* que deveria ter sido modificado o syso retorna:

```
[Item 1, Item 2, Item 3, Item 4, Item 5]
```

Onde estou errando?

Grato!

Answer (score 1):

Você está sempre instanciando um novo objeto quando esta adicionando um item e quando esta pegando a listagem para escrever. Assim, o item que você adicionou na instancia anterior nao esta inserido na instancia nova que você criou para escrever os itens da listagem.

Tente algo assim:

```
public class Principal {

public static void main(String[] args) {


        Produtos produtos = new Produtos();

        String nome = "x";

        String[] dummy = produtos.getNomeItem();

        String[] junta = new InsereElementos().insereElemento(dummy, nome);

        produtos.setNomeItem(junta);


        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(produtos.getNomeItem()));
    }
}
```

Com isso você mantem a mesma instância do objeto produtos, que você usa para inserir um novo item e depois escrever esse novo item inserido na sua coleção

Comment: Poxa cara, muito obrigado mesmo, está sendo difícil migrar do C pro Java, vou tentar ler mais para não fazer perguntas tão bobas!

Agradeço também o respeito/simpatia, diferentemente do coleguinha ali que não sabe nem o que é Syso.

Abraços

Comment: Cara, sem problemas, nunca se intimide de pergunta alguma coisa aqui, estamos aqui para justamente construir conhecimento em comunidade. Espero que tenha conseguido lhe ajudar em sua dúvida e respondido sua questão.